# Canvas on Canvas WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

Here's the situation. We have canvas with some controls on it:
[image: Simple canvas with the button]

We can click the button, it works. But when there is another canvas on the first one, like in the picture below (light yellow):

[image: Light yellow canvas on on the first canvas]

Button doesn't works anymore. I know that upper canvas blocks it. But how can we solve this situation, how to access the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you can set the Background of the top canvas to null (which should be the case by default), or set its IsHitTestVisible property to false.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping the button controls at the last of the XAML. so what ever you load in the grid of canvas, it wont block the button!